# Unsorted Priority Queue using Doubly Linked List in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement an unsorted priority queue using a doubly linked list in java. I have three interfaces for an entry class, priorityQueue class and a doubly class (doubly class just returns a getElement). As well as an abstract class for priorityQueue. Although I have just provided the DoublyLinkedList class and my MyPQUnsorted class. I think my error might be in the MyPQUnsorted. Any help would be much appreciated as I am really stuck on this one.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> 
{
    private static class Node<E> {
        private E element;
        private Node<E> prev;
        private Node<E> next;
        public Node(E e, Node<E> p, Node<E> n) {
        element = e; prev = p; next = n;
        }
    
    public E getElement() {return getElement(); }
    public Node<E> getPrev() { return prev; } 
    public Node<E> getNext() { return next; } 
    public void setPrev(Node<E> p) { prev = p; } 
    public void setNext(Node<E> n) { next = n; }
    }
    
    private Node<E> header;
    private Node<E> trailer;
    private int size = 0;
    
    public DoublyLinkedList( ) {
        header = new Node<>(null, null, null); 
        trailer = new Node<>(null, header, null); 
        header.setNext(trailer);
    }
    public int size() { return size; }
    
    public boolean isEmpty() { return size == 0; }
    
    public E first() 
    {
        if (isEmpty()) 
            return null;
        return header.getNext().getElement();
    }
    
    public E last() {
        if (isEmpty()) return null;
        return trailer.getPrev().getElement(); // last element is before trailer 
    }
    
    public void addFirst(E e) {
        addBetween(e, header, header.getNext());
        }
    public void addLast(E e) {
        addBetween(e, trailer.getPrev(), trailer);
    }
    
    public E removeFirst( ) {
        if (isEmpty()) return null; // nothing to remove
        return remove(header.getNext());
    }
    public E removeLast() {
        if (isEmpty()) return null;
        return remove(trailer.getPrev());
        }
    private void addBetween(E e, Node<E> predecessor, Node<E> successor) {
         // create and link a new node
         Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, predecessor, successor);
         predecessor.setNext(newest);
         successor.setPrev(newest);
         size++;
         }
    
    private E remove(Node<E> node) {
         Node<E> predecessor = node.getPrev( );
         Node<E> successor = node.getNext( );
         predecessor.setNext(successor);
         successor.setPrev(predecessor);
         size--;
         return node.getElement();
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyPQUnsorted<K,V> extends AbstractPriorityQueue<K,V> 
{
    public MyPQUnsorted() { super(); }
    public MyPQUnsorted(Comparator<K> comp) { super(comp); } 
    private DoublyLinkedList<Entry<K,V>> list = new DoublyLinkedList<>();

    private Doubly<Entry<K,V>> findMin()
    {
        Doubly<Entry<K,V>> small = list.first();
        Doubly<Entry<K,V>> walk;
        while (!walk.isEmpty())
        {
            if (compare(walk.getElement(), small.getElement()) < 0) 
                small = walk; // found an even smaller key
        }
        return small; 
    }
     
    public Entry<K,V> insert(K key, V value) throws IllegalArgumentException 
    { 
        checkKey(key);
        Entry<K,V> newest = new PQEntry<>(key, value);
        list.addLast(newest);
        return newest;
    }
    
    public Entry<K,V> min() 
    {
        if (list.isEmpty()) 
            return null;
        return findMin().getElement();
    }
        
    public Entry<K,V> removeMin() 
    {
        if (list.isEmpty()) 
            return null;
        return list.remove(findMin()); 
    }
    
    public int size() { return list.size(); }
}
```

Comment: "Unsorted Priority Queue" sounds like an oxymoron... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: My best interpretation was a heap (ie the queue isn't literally sorted in memory but if you pop stuff off it comes out in order), based on what I see here.

Comment: I have to use a priority queue that supports the following methods: insert(k,v), min(), removeMin(), size(), isEmpty() which I already implemented in my priorityQueue interface but now I need to create the implementation of the doubly linked list which i am having trouble on @htuy42

Comment: What is the behavior that you want which you haven't got? Is there some error your are getting? Etc. I can't tell exactly what the problem is from the question, unless the question is just "how would you implement a priority queue / doubly linked list", in which case you can just go see the source for the java library implementations of these.

Comment: In this case I am getting the error in my "MyPQUnsorted<K,V>" class. I am trying to find the smallest node element in the DoublyLinkedList but not sure how to do it as it is giving me errors @htuy42

Comment: What, specifically, is the error tho